# Compare 2 object by keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, compare

I have two objects:

```
let obj1 = {
  username: Jake,
  progress: 100
};

let obj2 = {
  username: Jake,
  progress: 200,
  updatedAt: timestamphere
};
```

I want function which will return true if certain keys in those 2 object not the same.

For example it would be `username` and `progress` but not `updatedAt` (would be more when 1.

> function compareObjectsByKeys(keys);

for example:

```
if (compareObjectsByKeys(['username', 'progress']) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: What's the use of passing through `['username', 'progress']` ? is it to check if `obj1` and `obj2` have these keys?

Comment: @NickParsons yes if `obj1` and `obj2` will have different value for `username` and `progress` its should return true.

Comment: What have you tried?  Your question should show some effort to solve the problem yourself or at least some specific questions about where you got stuck.

Comment: This comparison, would it also try to compare objects? Like arrays, functions, regex, date, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `every` first to make sure all the keys are in both objects, then use `some` to check the alternate values.

```js
const obj1 = {username:"Jake",progress:100};
const obj2 = {username:"Jake",progress:200,updatedAt:"timestamphere"};

const compareObjectsByKeys = keys => keys.every(key => key in obj1 && key in obj2) && keys.some(key => obj1[key] != obj2[key]);

console.log(compareObjectsByKeys(["username", "progress"]));
```

Comment: If you are checking every key already, why not include the comparison on the `every` call as well?

Comment: Because if one key out of two doesn't match, then `every` will still return `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass both objects as well

```
compareObjectsByKeys(obj1, obj2, keys) {
    for (key of keys) {
        if (obj1[key] !== obj2[key]) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

with `keys` being an array of strings

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.every()` on your keys array, to check whether each key-value pair from object one is equal to that of object two. I've also used `JSON.stringify` so that we can compare arrays and other objects.

```js
const obj1 = {
  username: 'Jake',
  progress: 100
};

const obj2 = {
  username: 'Jake',
  progress: 200,
  updatedAt: 'timestamphere'
}

function compareObjectsByKeys(keys) {
  return !keys.every(k => k in obj1 && k in obj2 && JSON.stringify(obj1[k]) === JSON.stringify(obj2[k]));
}

console.log(compareObjectsByKeys(['username', 'progress'])); // true 
console.log(compareObjectsByKeys(['username'])); // false
console.log(compareObjectsByKeys(['foo'])); // true (in this case undefined != undefined)
```